# App apresenta scroll estranho no iPhone 6

Tags: xcode, iphone

Minha aplicação passou a apresentar um tela menor quando rodo no iphone 6. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Segue a tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Grato

Comment: Você desenvolveu seu aplicativo usando modo de compatibilidade com outros dispositivos de telas maiores? Tente usar `anchors` ou `dock` nos seus objetos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É preciso um pouco mais de informações para dar uma resposta precisa.

Aplicativos mais "antigos", que usam XIB, tendem a funcionar porque o XIB para iPhone 5 é automaticamente escalonado nos iPhones 6/6+, já que a proporção da tela (16:9) é a mesma.

Aplicativos que usam o tipo antigo de splash screen (imagens Default*.png) também escalonam automaticamente, porque se presume que foram feitos para iPhone 5 ou menor. Quando você troca o splash screen estático por um XIB ou tela do Storyboard, está sinalizando que o app é compatível com iPhone 6/6+ e aí as questões de tamanho de tela diferente aparecem.

Se você está usando aqueles recursos mais novos de desenho de tela (Storyboard, AutoLayout), você tem de retrabalhar o projeto de tela para ele adaptar-se a diferentes tamanhos, adicionando constraints. Se a tela está toda desenhada com posições e tamanhos absolutos, acontece exatamente o que aparece na sua figura: a interface não ocupa a tela toda. Você tem de partir para tamanhos relativos, baseados em constraints.

Pelo menos esta é minha experiência, comente se seu problema não se enquadra...